# An appropriate phrase/idiom/ word for "trying hard to understand"

Tags: word-usage

What would be a good way to say "I have been **trying hard to understand the solution** for a long time"?

Comment: Most people would use your suggestion.

Comment: I've been ["racking my brains"...](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rack-your-brains)...

Comment: How long have you been “*beating your head against the wall*” on this one?

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if it's the cadance that's troubling you? The sentence is gramatically correct, and the thought is clearly stated, but it doesn't exactly 'roll off the tongue', does it? 
If that's the case, here are a couple of alternatives that might jog the rhythm:

> I've been struggling to comprehend the solution for quite some time;
>    Despite my efforts, the solution continues to evade my comprehension.
>       (HaHa! Idly wondering whether you're composing a letter to a mathmatics professor, or the publisher of a puzzle book! ;)

Answer (score 1):

"Trying hard to understand" captures what you mean, I think. It's quite clear.

Depending on context, I might suggest replacing "solution" with "answer," but there's nothing wrong with the way you have expressed it.